# Css fluid layout with fixed and responsive elements

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid

I have this layout:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="prev"></div>
  <div class="pause"></div>
  <div class="seekbar"></div>
  <div class="next"></div>
  <div class="volume"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a9vvckwd/1/

Let and right divs and fixed size, while div in the middle is responsive.

How can I make this if I delete any of the fixed divs left or right of the responsive div, this responsive div will expand to fill the size of the wrapper?

(with just css, cross browser)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:flex` and  `flex-grow: 1;` can do it.

Give `display: flex;` to `#wrapper` and `.seekbar` to `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
.prev {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}
.pause {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ba7;
}
.seekbar {
  height: 40px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: green;
}
.next {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
.volume {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ad3;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="prev"></div>

  <div class="pause"></div>

  <div class="seekbar"></div>

  <div class="next"></div>

  <div class="volume"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `display: table` and `table-layout: fixed` and set fixed widths for the non-fluid divs.

This will work in IE8+ and all real browsers.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
}

#wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.prev {
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
}
.pause {
  width: 40px;
  background: #ba7;
}
.seekbar {
  background: green;
}
.next {
  width: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
.volume {
  width: 40px;
  background: #ad3;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="prev"></div>

  <div class="pause"></div>

  <div class="seekbar"></div>

  <div class="next"></div>

  <div class="volume"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.prev {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: red;
}
.pause {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: #ba7;
}
.seekbar {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
.next {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: blue;
}
.volume {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: #ad3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="prev"></div>

  <div class="pause"></div>

  <div class="seekbar"></div>

  <div class="next"></div>

  <div class="volume"></div>

</div>


<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="prev"></div>


  <div class="seekbar"></div>


  <div class="volume"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you can use display:table property instead of position

working fiddle



     https://jsfiddle.net/a9vvckwd/3/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a9vvckwd/3/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes